# Как зашифровать текст при записи в файл и расшифровывать его при открытии?

Tags: c#, шифрование

Пишу маленькую программу для чтения/записи текста. Первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь, так как пока что я новичок в C#, хотелось бы посмотреть на простой пример.

*Сложные решение думаю пока что не смогу понять.*

Comment: см. классы в System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: _"новичек в си"_ -- так в си или c#?

Comment: @Stack ну зачем новичку все так серьезно. Пусть для начала просто байты поксорит. К сожалению не пишу на C#, поэтому код показать не могу.

Comment: Уже поправил, в c#

Comment: _"Как зашифровать текст при записи в файл"_ -- Stream для записи пропускаете через CryptoStream. пример тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/968007/5673266

Comment: примеры на чтение/запись в файл тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо за подсказки, по ним я нашел очень простой пример, правда нужно будет более детально в нем разобраться, но все же он очень простой.

**Шифруем текст, и записываем его в файл**

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
   cryptic.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);


byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World!");

crStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);

crStream.Close();
stream.Close();
```

**Дешифруем текст и выводим результат дешифрации в консоль**

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.txt", 
                              FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
    cryptic.CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Read);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream);

string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.ReadKey();

reader.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Теперь осталось понять работу ключей, почитать мануал. что бы действительно понимать как все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за хороший пример. Если вы хотите что бы корректно отображался кириллический текст то при записи следует немого изменить код при записи.

```
       var dstEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
       FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);


        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
        cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
           cryptic.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);


        byte[] data = dstEncoding.GetBytes("Hello World!");

        crStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);

        crStream.Close();
        stream.Close();
```